# newbie trying to use IO::Socket on Windows

Tags: perl

I am new to IO::SOCKET and new to network programming. I have read few online tutorials regarding the same. I am running Perl on Windows :( have no other choice. My over goal is to connect a 2 processes via socket on local machine. One process is Perl script that controls equipment via GPIB commands. Other process is a .exe file with Socket connection ( something like Server program with Socket connection ).

Here is what i am planning to do. In my Perl script create a client socket and connect it to the .exe socket ( via port ). fork client program for read/write operation. The problem is I don't know where to start the coding from. I guess I need one more main Perl script and make the other Perl script that controls equipment via GPIB as Perl module.

I would appreciate for some feedback on this thought and some programming example on the socket connection.

Comment: You can start from examples on http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket/INET.html

Comment: Ivan, that's not so good advice for two reasons: that piece of documentation is useful only for people who already know what they're doing; and you neglect to mention that IO::Socket::INET should be used with Perl 5.14 and better only because earlier versions are IPv4-only, and it's a bad idea to write IPv4-only software in 2011.

Comment: I guess If i am running the application on local machine I need not worry about IP4 or IP6 ?...

Comment: @user2829, If you use IO::Socket::IP as he showed below, you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 4):

Run the ominous server executable. It binds to a port and starts listening. To have a meaningful data exchange over the socket, you need to know three things:

1. host name
2. port number
3. protocol, i.e. what to say when you talk to the server, and how to interpret its answers

---

```
use IO::Socket::IP qw(SOCK_STREAM);
my $socket = IO::Socket::IP->new(
    PeerHost => $host_name,
    PeerPort => $port_number,
    Type     => SOCK_STREAM,    # Transmission Control Protocol
) or die "Cannot construct socket - $@";
$socket->say('Hello, server! How are you doing?');
say for $socket->getlines;
```

The relevant documentation about the available methods is in [IO::Socket::IP](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aIP), [IO::Socket](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aSocket) and [IO::Handle](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aHandle).