# Interprocess communication in windows xp

Tags: perl, tcp, ipc, tk-toolkit

I have least knowledge on network domain.Please bare with my question if it is basic

I would like to know how to communicate between two applications using **TCP/ip protocol** in
   **windows XP** say for example

**Using Perl and TK I am building a GUI with entry widget and i have an other external application which is installed in the system say APPLICATION.exe**

Now i need to establish the connection using **TCP** between my perl program and external application APPLICATION.exe

for testing purpose what ever I type in the GUI Entry this external application has to receive (hope it receives as bytes)and external application will send some data and i need to process that data in my perl program..

I am totally unaware whether this is simple task or complicated.
If there are any modules existing in perl for similar programming please suggest me.
I highly appreciate if anyone can provide me the answer with an example.

Thanks to all

Comment: Nothing Windows specific here, btw.

Comment: Are you writing APPLICATION.exe as well, or is it a third party application?

Comment: its a third party application which has build in TCP/IP API.. I need to configure my perl program it requires socket,address and port..How to configure those things... means how to identify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple if you have done network programming before. If not, it is intermediately difficult because you need to get a grip on the underlying concepts and terminology first - read a book about the topic if necessary.

I recommend to use [IO::Socket::IP](http://p3rl.org/IO::Socket::IP). If you have Perl 5.14 or later, you can also use [IO::Socket::INET](http://p3rl.org/IO::Socket::INET) that is distributed with Perl. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8582550/46395 for a code example and links to further documentation.